# How to test my SSL certificates for indy smtp and pop3 servers?

Tags: ssl, smtp, indy, pop3

Can someone show me an effective way to test if my self-signed SSL certificates are working properly - I have TIdSMTPServer and TIdPOP3Server along with TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL in my application and I do this :

```
IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.CertFile := 'myCert.crt';
IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.RootCertFile := 'myCert.crt';
IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.KeyFile := 'myKey.key';
POP3Server.IOHandler := IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1;
SMTPServer.IOHandler := IdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL1;
SMTPServer.Bindings.Add.Port := 465;
POP3Server.Bindings.Add.Port := 995;
```

Then I send/receive some emails through the SSL ports (smtp - 465, pop3 - 995), but I don't know how to test if my certificates are actually attached to my SMTP and POP3 servers and if they are - are they supplying me with an SSL connection between client and server ?

Comment: Certificates do not provide SSL connections. They simply provide identity verification so the client can verify that it is actually talking to the server it thinks it is talking to, and vice versa, instead of a man-in-the-middle attacker.  SSL does not require certificates.  The fact that you connect to SSL-protected ports is enough to establish SSL connections, certificates are just extra protection.

Comment: BTW, if you are using Indy 10, you need to manually activate SSL in a server's OnConnect event, by setting the accepted client connection's `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(IOHandler).PassThrough` to False, otherwise the connection will not be encrypted. This is by design so you can check which Port the client connected to if you want to run both SSL and non-SSL ports in the same server. Indy 9 does not let you do that, SSL is always active by default regardless of Port used if you have an SSL IOHander assigned to the server.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - yes, I am using Indy 10, but I didn't fully understand what to add to my two onconnect events - can you provide an example how my code should look like in these two events : 

    procedure Pop3ServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    begin 
    { manage ssl connection }
    end;
    procedure SMTPServerConnect(AContext: TIdContext);
    begin
    { manage ssl connection }
    end;

Comment: @RemyLebeau - If I type this 
TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := False;
in my two server onconnect events my application stops sending/receiving emails with client error "Connection closed gracefully". What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Double check the IOHandler is the right class type and the client is on the right port. For example, SMTP: `if AContext.Connection.IOHandler is TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase then TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase(AContext.Connection.IOHandler).PassThrough := (AContext.Binding.Port <> 465);` Put a breakpoint and step through it to make sure everything is what it should be.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - thanks a lot again, man - now my client application connects ok :)